# Localhost not working with xampp

Tags: xampp, localhost

After installing xampp earlier I had troubles with apache not starting but fixed it just by making it a service.
But now every time i try and go on my *http://localhost/xampp/* it says

```
Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
```

and same with chrome

I have evrything started in xampp control panel
and I have a windows 7 computer (if it makes a differance) and I have xampp version 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

the current version of *xampp* is *1.8.1*

imho you are using *openemr-xampp-3.1.0*

about the problem that you are facing please ensure that apache is listening on default port *80*..if it is listening on some other port say *8080* then you have to type your url like *http://localhost:8080**emphasized text*

Also, make sure that so other software or service like skype is using port 80..try to stop such services in case anything like that exists..